# How to remove these embedded documents from MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a field which is a dictionary of embedded documents (I hope my terminology is right). I'm trying to remove all embedded documents (from this dictionary) where the key is NOT `abc`.

This mongo script works great:

```
db.getCollection("users").update(
    {},
    {
        $unset: 
        { 
            "prefs.state.AAAA": "",
            "prefs.state.BBBB": "",
            "prefs.state.CCCC": "",
        } 
    },
    {
        multi: true
    }
);
```

My problem here is that I actually don't know all the possible key's, in this dictionary list.

In the above example, i have

- AAAA
- BBBB
- CCCC

but i could have a heap more.

here's an example legit document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "prefs" : {
        "state" : {
            "abc123" : { // TO STAY
                "name" : "name1", 
                "age" : 1.0
            }, 
            "AAAA" : { // TO BE REMOVED
                "name" : "name2", 
                "age" : 2.0
            }, 
            "XASDASD" : { // TO BE REMOVED
                "name" : "name3", 
                "age" : 3.0
            }
        }
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2.0, 
    "prefs" : {
        "state" : {} // NO DATA, but this is OK
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : 3.0, 
    "prefs" : {
        "state" : {
            "CCCC" : { // TO BE REMOVED
                "name" : "name4", 
                "age" : 4.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what i'm trying to do is this:

If `prefs.state.<KEY>` doesn't equal `abc123` then this embedded document should be nuked.

So given the mongo script above, it will find `prefs.state.AAAA` and unset that field, which bascially nukes that embedded doc.

Is this possible?

---

Update 1: here's the shell output (which shows it fails). I ran this in the app "Studio 3T"

Script:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("users");


db.getCollection("jussytest").updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "prefs.state": {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: { $objectToArray: "$prefs.state" },
                            as: "x",
                            cond: { $eq: ["$$x.k", "abc123"] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
    
 db.getCollection("jussytest").find({});
```

Result:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.16
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/users
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("1ae46c5b-a711-4f56-adb4-5e5f8a093750") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.3
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
users
authenticated
users
2021-03-10T09:17:43.659+1100 E QUERY    [js] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :

DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1

@(shell):1:1

The find query will be run with Query Assist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this update pipeline a try (make sure to not try on production data):

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                "prefs.state": {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: { $objectToArray: "$prefs.state" },
                            as: "x",
                            cond: { $eq: ["$$x.k", "abc123"] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply - really appreciate it. Have you tried this, yourself? I couldn't get it to run in mongodb shell. got an error: `Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`. i did this on a test db i quickly started, with those 3x documents.

Comment: @Pure.Krome yes I tested it. I assumed you are on a recent version of mongo. I believe the pipeline update support was added in version 4.2 if I'm not mistaken. if your mongo version is >=4.2 then your she'll version might be old.

Comment: im on the latest version of mongodb docker image. hmm. I'll update the post with the shell output.

Comment: @Pure.Krome looks like you need to update the shell. `v4.0.16` doesn't support pipeline updates. the command works. [see here](https://youtu.be/tORoo7p323o)

Comment: OMG. seriously! As in, i'm sooooo not hating you @Đĵ-ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ but hating how complicated this tooling is/can be  ! oof ... /me goes off and finds out if Studio 3T can select/change/upgrade the shell. . . .. .  YES! and WOOT! it works! Whoa. Dude - you're a ⭐!! Okay - in an hour or so i'll try this again against (a copy of) some production data with real key names (not dummy key's, above). 

Comment: Sigh: `"$objectToArray requires a document input, found: string"`  /me tries to learn what these now means .. and more importantly, which documents are killing the query.

Comment: @Pure.Krome yeah it's gonna be troublesome if all the documents are not in a consistent shape. alternatively you could just filter out the docs that have strings in the `prefs.state` field with `{ "prefs.state": { $not: { $type: 2 } } }` instead of the empty filter `{}`

Comment: Yeah @Đĵ-ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ yep - i'm stuck with that grief. I also tried that last night, doing various filters (the first argument of the `updateMany` method. I tried to also do filters for null checks and `$not $type` checks, also. still getting errors. I feel like i'm so close! (BTW, I still think your current answer is the right answer, though). This is a case of 'bad data', now